# DotNetOpenAuth: when is StoreNewRequestToken called?

Tags: c#, oauth, dotnetopenauth

I'm trying to implement DotNetOpenAuth, without using an OpenId-provider.
Getting a `RequestToken` does not work on my implementation.

I'm calling a method, which calls the `ServiceProvider.ReadRequest()`.
This is calling the `IServiceProviderTokenManager.GetRequestToken(string token)`.
At this point, no `RequestToken` is found, because I was expecting this method to create a `RequestToken`.

But creating a `RequestToken` is handled by the method `StoreNewRequestToken`.
When does this method get called?
Or how can I make this method being called?

Comment: DotNetOpenAuth has at least 5 major scenarios (OpenID Provider being only one).  Can you adjust your question to say what you're trying to do instead of what you're *not* trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your OAuth SP host code is either miswritten or the Consumer is possibly providing a token from an earlier attempt.  Please [activate logging](http://tinyurl.com/dnoalogs) and add logs to your question.

I believe DotNetOpenAuth calls your `StoreNewRequestToken` method when you are actually transmitting your response to the Consumer using `ServiceProvider.PrepareUnauthorizedTokenMessage` and sending its result using `ServiceProvider.Channel.Send`.  Before that, I don't think DNOA should be calling your `GetRequestToken` yet because the Consumer shouldn't have any token to try with -- thus my earlier suggestion that the consumer is possibly using an old token (or malfunctioning).

Comment: Thanks for answering, even though my question was not that clear. I definitely think this is pushing me in the right direction. Since I'm still developing, it might be my implementation is correct, but I'm firing a call with an incorrect OAuth-header. I will investigate.

Comment: Yep, I messed up my header and was sending a token. Thanks for putting me in the right direction.